# VS Code - how to find all references in a rails application

Tags: visual-studio-code

To be clear, I'm talking about Visual Studio **Code**, the lightweight text editor from Microsoft.

I'm working on a rails application. I don't know if the feature exists at all, is it a language specific thing.

I'd like to find all references of an object (method, variable etc..), but in the whole application folder, not only it's declaration file.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: use `grep` in the console.

Comment: I know `grep` of course, even vim's all-powerful magic. Still, I like VS Code better and I want to perfect my workflow with it. In short: I do not want to use grep.

Comment: OP - were you able to find the solution? I am also searching for a stable solution for ruby code. Solargraph gem has it but its in dev state.

Comment: This is covered by using F12 w/ Language support (see https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved) and has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658665/navigate-to-ruby-function-definition-in-vs-code